# How to rectify the no wrap(head) JavaScript from jsFiddle to HTML to get it working

Tags: javascript, html, css, slide

Few days ago, I posted a query regarding a concept of a slide. 
stumbled upon this exact concept right here.
http://jsfiddle.net/JCQ6Q/15/

However, I'm facing a problem. 
in Js Fiddle, everything seems to be working out fine. 
but When I compile it on the HTML editor software on my local host, It doesn't run :( 
The images are stack on top of one another & a scroll bar appears.

It may be because on JsFiddle, the framework is put to *no wrap(head)* 
If Its put to the default *onLoad* ,  the same thing happens as it does in my HTML

any inputs on how i can correctly put the javascript on the HTML?

Comment: view source http://fiddle.jshell.net/JCQ6Q/15/show/

Comment: @canon, I was wondering if it is possible to ease in the opacity as the slide comes into to the center. I believe it has to be with the JavaScript....i tried putting the easing jquery Script but it had no effect on it....any idea how it can be possible?
eg: like this effect as it comes to the center....the opacity is smooth http://www.harvard.edu/

Answer (score 1):

The error in the console is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'anythingSlider'
```

Your plugin script is being included too late (`.ready()` executes before `.load()`). Make sure to structure your HTML something like this:

```
<script src="plugin.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#slider').anythingSlider({
            autoPlay: true,
            autoPlayLocked: true,
            buildStartStop: false
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it..i got the workng HTML from here.... http://fiddle.jshell.net/JCQ6Q/15/show/ .was wondering if it is possible to ease in the opacity as the slide comes into to the center. I believe it has to be with the JavaScript....i tried putting the easing jquery Script but it had no effect on it....any idea how it can be possible? eg: like this effect as it comes to the center....the opacity is smooth http://www.harvard.edu/

Answer (score 0):

Did you test with :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your code
});
```

It seems that it works on jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JCQ6Q/17/)

Comment: Thanks for looking into it....i got the workng HTML from here....http://fiddle.jshell.net/JCQ6Q/15/show/